# Create group with multiple names - Ansible GCE inventory plugin

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I want to create a dynamic inventory, and create a group to put the nodes where I scrape data from.I'm using the gcp_compute plugin in my dynamic inventory.

What I want to achieve:
I want to retrieve multiple hostnames/ip and put them in the same group. I want it to be quite modular, so I can switch nodenames easily.

This how it looks so far:

```
plugin: gcp_compute
auth_kind: serviceaccount
cache: true
gather_facts: false
retrieve_image_info: true
service_account_file: servicefile.json
groups:
  node_exporter: "'db-vm' in name"
```

I want to use something like: `node_exporter: "'db-vm' OR 'prometheus-vm' in name"` or something similar. How can I achieve this.

This is the command I use too see if it works or not: `ansible-inventory -i gce_inventory.gcp.yml --graph`. All my nodes gets ungrouped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it very easily...

I believe I made some mistakes before when doing the conditional, but now accidentally solved it.

To be able to retrieve multiple, here how:
`node_exporter: "'db-vm' in name or 'prometheus-vm' in name"`